# MVC log-in redirecting to wrong page on login/logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

ASP.NET MVC5 web site, which didn't have any auth when I created it, so I don't have any of the built-in auth code.

I have now added an Admin controller, which will contain a single page/action (Index) for some admin stuff, and have also added a LogIn action to it...

```
public class AdminController : Controller {
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Index() {
    // TODO - Add the admin stuff
    return View();
  }

  #region LogIn

  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Login() {
    return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel livm) {
    if (livm.UserName != "uid" || livm.Password != "pwd") {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your user name and password were not recognised. Please try again");
      livm.Password = "";
      return View(livm);
    }
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(livm.UserName, false);
    return Content("OK", "text/text");
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**NOTE** that I'm using a hard-coded user name and password for testing. Once it's working, I'll change that!

LoginViewModel is a simple class that has properties for the user name and password, with some useful attributes.

The web.config file contains the following...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login" />
</authentication>
```

...and the log in view looks like this...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Admin", new {ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"})) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "form-control", title = "your user name"})
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control", title = "Your password"})
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input id="logInBtn" type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Now, if you try and access /Admin or /Admin/Index, you are correctly redirected to http://localhost:7154/Admin/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fIndex, where you can enter your user name and password.

Here's where it goes wrong. When you click the Log In button, you are redirected to http://localhost:7154/default.aspx, which gives a 404, as the page doesn't exist.

How do I make it so that it redirects to the requested URL? In this case, I don't mind hard-coded a redirect to /Admin, as that's currently the only secured page there will be, but I would like to know how to redirect to whatever page the user requested, in case I add any other secure bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form definition:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Admin", new {ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
```

You are adding to a route parameters `ReturnUrl`. In order to use it 
add additional argument to your Login action:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel livm, string returnUrl) {
    if (livm.UserName != "uid" || livm.Password != "pwd") {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your user name and password were not recognised. Please try again");
      livm.Password = "";
      return View(livm);
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(livm.UserName, false);
    //Assuming that user's login was successful simply redirect him to the requested url:
    return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

  }


  private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
  {
      if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
      {
          return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
      }          
      //Default redirect:
      return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I wasted ages trying to sort this out. Don't know why they make it so complex!